# Sending information to 3 random websites from a list of 6 using curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a mailer that sends solo ads to a small network of similar sites, but I want to change it so that the solo is sent to 3 random sites from the list, not to all of them.  I only have very basic PHP knowledge and have spent many hours trying to work this out and checking forums.  I assume I'll have to set up an array, but don't know where to start.  Here is the relevant coding of the file:

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 include "../config.php";
 include "../header.php";
 include "../style.php";
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $id = $_POST['id'];

 if($_SESSION['admin'] != $adminpw) {

    ?><table>
    <tr>
    <td width="15%" valign=top><br>
    <? include("adminnavigation.php"); ?>
    </td>
    <td  valign="top" align="center"><br><br> <?
    echo "<font size=2 face='$fonttype' color='$fontcolour'><p><b><center>";



    if($_POST['submit'] == "Delete") {


    foreach($id as $each) {
    mysql_query ("update solos set added=0, approved=0, subject='',  adbody='', url='' where id=".$each);
    }

    echo "<p><center>The solos have been sent back to the users.</p></center>";
    } else {

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    foreach($id as $each) {
    mysql_query ("update solos set approved=1, date='".time()."' where id=".$each);


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM solos WHERE id=".$each);
    $info = mysql_fetch_array($sql);


                    // Work out the data
                     $wannasay = array (
                            "subject" => $info['subject'],
                            "adbody" => $info['adbody'],
                            "userid" => $info['userid'],
                            "url" => $domain."/solo_click.php?id=".$info['id']
                            );
                     $dataels = array();
                     foreach (array_keys($wannasay) as $thiskey) {
                            array_push($dataels,urlencode($thiskey) ."=".
                                            urlencode($wannasay[$thiskey]));
                            }
 $data = implode("&",$dataels);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE1.COM/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE2.com/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE3.com/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE4.com/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE5.com/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.WEBSITE6.com/admin/solo_curl.php");
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $page = curl_exec($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);
```

This is the file for approving the solo ad in admin, and the information is then sent to the relevant file at the other sites for placement in the database.  I want the solo ad sent to 3 random sites every time I approve a solo ad, so really only need the coding to make this happen.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after `$data = implode("&",$dataels);` add the following:

```
$website_array = array(
    0 => 'website1.com/admin/solo_curl.php',
    1 => 'website2.com/admin/solo_curl.php',
    2 => 'website3.com/admin/solo_curl.php',
    3 => 'website4.com/admin/solo_curl.php',
    4 => 'website5.com/admin/solo_curl.php',
    5 => 'website6.com/admin/solo_curl.php'
);
$rand_keys = array_rand($website_array, 3);
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    $website_to_send_to = $website_array[$key];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $website_to_send_to);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

And remove all your cURL sections.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Have only sent the one out so far, but it sent to 3 of the sites and tomorrow I can send another, but all looks fine.  Thanks very much.